# How to find only the users who have posted at least one comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails 2.3.5 .

This is a standard case. Tables are: users, comments, user_comments . I need to find all the users who have status 'active' and have posted at least one comment.

I know comments table can have foreign key but this is a contrived example. There are two users in the table. There are two comments. Both the comments are posted by the first user.

```
named_scope :with_atleast_one_comment, lambda { {
      :joins => 'inner join user_comments on users.id = user_comments.user_id ' } }


 named_scope :with_active_status, {:conditions => {:status => 'active'} }
```

When I execute

```
 User.with_atleast_one_comment.with_active_status
```

I get two records. Since both the comments are posted by one user I want only one user.

What's the fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The with_at_least_one_comment scope isn't behaving as you expect it to. As it appears in the question, it will select a user for each entry in user_comments. Which results in the duplicate results you're seeing. When compounded with active_users, you will remove any records returned by with_at_least_one_comment that don't have active status.

Let's start by simplifying the problematic named scope first.
You don't need the lambda because there are no arguments to take, and the join can be outsourced to Active Record, which performs an inner join if given an association.

In short, this named scope will do exactly what you want.

```
named_scope :with_at_least_one_comment, :joins => :user_comments, 
  :group => 'users.id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the :uniq => true option to remove duplicates from the collection. This is most useful in conjunction with the :through option.

Comment: ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): uniq if I do  named_scope :with_atleast_one_comment, lambda { {
      :uniq => true,
      :joins => 'inner join user_comments on users.id = user_comments.user_id ' } }

Answer (score 0):

if i'm is not wrong, there is few way to achieve this...

unless User.comments?
or another way is also specify a new method in your controller 
and lastly...
the info from Emfi should work
have a try for it~

Comment: Your suggestions aren't bad. But they're negating the advantages of named_scopes. Which is the optimization of delaying population of ActiveRecord objects until only desired records are selected. Relying on a new controller method or unless user.comments, requires selecting all Users populating AR objects and discarding the unwanted ones. Which will result in very large SQL queries/responses, major slow down under heavy use and could possibly throw off pagination.

Comment: yea...you are right~
my fault is never mind about app performance
so...last conclusion 
the answer from Emfi is the best...